# Would a perfect cube of lesser density float if placed perfectly on the surface of a liquid container?

Tags: buoyancy

If a cube -"of lesser density than the liquid"- with perfectly flat surfaces was placed in a liquid container with a perfectly flat bottom , so that there were no liquid molecules between the two surfaces (maybe place the cube and then fill the container with the liquid while temporally holding the cube down) , would the cube float ?

Comment: What do *you* think would happen? And why do you expect that?

Comment: If when you place the cube in the empty bottom you cannot lift it up, i.e. no air molecules have penetrated and there is complete suction, then there is a chance also liquid molecules will not penetrate.

Comment: I think the question needs an edit. If the surfaces were somewhat near atomically flat (below the micrometer range) we'd have [sticktion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiction) and if there was liquid between the two it would be [floating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/floating) (buoyed on or in a fluid). Some portion of the object needs to touch (but not necessarily be in [intimate contact](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-13592-7_1) with) the bottom to be *non-floating*, even under the surface.